# Linked list search to stop loops before they happen

Tags: python

I have a series of frames, and each frame can either be `None` or point to another frame. I don't want anything looping back to itself, so I'd like a quick way to check which frames are available for a certain frame to point to.

For example, if frame 1 points to 2, and frame 2 points to 3, then I'd like to know that frame 3 cannot point to either 1 or 2, as it would cause a loop. If frame 3 is pointing to 4, then 4 is still valid.

As an example, take the pointers as this:

```
frame_pointers = {5: 6,
                  6: 7,
                  7: 8,
                  8: None,
                  9: 10,
                  10: None,
                  11: 9,
                  12: 6}
```

Here's the expected result of what each frame can point to:

```
5: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
6: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11] (since 5 and 12 are pointing at it)
7: [8, 9, 10, 11] (since 6 is pointing at it and 5 and 12 are at 6)
8: [9, 10, 11] (since 7 is pointing at it and 6 at 7 etc)
9: [5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12]
10: [5, 6, 7, 8, 12]
11: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12]
12: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Basically, I just need to check what is pointing towards it, or pointing to anything else that's pointing towards it.

Here was my first attempt, using recursion to iterate through all the values:

```
def get_valid_links(pointers, current_frame):

    current_value = pointers[current_frame]
    frames = []
    for j in sorted(pointers.keys()):

        #Make sure there will be no clashes
        if j != current_value:

            #Ignore value if it matches the selected frame
            if j == current_frame:
                continue
            value = pointers[j]

            #Ignore value if it has an immediate link to the current frame
            if value == current_frame:
                continue

            elif value is not None:
                #Check if it has any links
                if recursive_search(j):
                    continue
        frames.append(j)
    return frames

def recursive_search(frame):

    #Similar function to above
    for j in sorted(frame_pointers.keys()):
        value = frame_pointers[j]
        if value == frame:
            return True
        elif value is not None:
            if recursive_search(value):
                return True
    return False

for i in sorted(frame_pointers.keys()):
    print 'Frames accessible to {}: {}'.format(i, ', '.join(map(str, get_valid_links(frame_pointers, i))))
```

And here is my second attempt, using a node class to make the searching easier:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, c=None, p=None):
        self.c = c
        self.p = p if p else []
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node(c={x.c}, p={x.p})'.format(x=self)

def build_linked_list(pointers):
    """Create list of Nodes"""
    new_list = {}
    sorted_keys = sorted(frame_pointers.keys())
    for k in sorted_keys:
        parents = []
        for j in sorted_keys:
            if frame_pointers[j] == k:
                parents.append(j)
        new_list[k] = Node(c=frame_pointers[k], p=parents)
    return new_list

def recursive_search(start_frame, end_frame, linked_list, visited_nodes=None):
    """Twin linked list type search"""
    if visited_nodes is None:
        visited_nodes = [start_frame]
    else:
        visited_nodes = list(visited_nodes) + [start_frame]
    frame = linked_list[start_frame]

    if start_frame == end_frame:
        return True

    if frame.c is not None and frame.c not in visited_nodes:
        if recursive_search(frame.c, end_frame, linked_list, visited_nodes):
            return True

    for j in frame.p:
        if j == end_frame:
            return True
        if j is not None and j not in visited_nodes:
            if recursive_search(j, end_frame, linked_list, visited_nodes):
                return True

def recursive_wrapper(start_frame, linked_list):
    all_values = [start_frame]
    for j in linked_list[start_frame].p:
        if recursive_search(j, start_frame, linked_list):
            all_values.append(j)
    return [i for i in linked_list.keys() if i not in all_values]


for i in frame_pointers:
    print recursive_wrapper(i, build_linked_list(frame_pointers))
```

Both don't work, but due to the nature of the search (I have managed to do a normal twin linked one before), I'm not quite sure what part needs fixing. If anyone could help with something like the first one, which would run faster, that'd be great, otherwise anything that works would still be good, I've spent hours trying to figure this out with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that each frame can only point to one other frame, a simple way to go about this would be, for every frame, to build the sequence of frames that follow. Then, we can check to see if a given frame is in that sequence. If so, then having that given frame point to the initial frame of the sequence would create a loop.

```
def get_valid_links(pointers, current_frame):
    allowed_frames = []

    for frame in pointers:
        if frame == current_frame:
            continue

        sequence = []
        next_frame = pointers[frame]
        while next_frame:
            sequence.append(next_frame)
            next_frame = pointers[next_frame]

        if current_frame not in sequence:
            allowed_frames.append(frame)

    return allowed_frames
```

I'm not sure what the performance would be like for a very large number of frames. But then maybe you could cache the results, etc.

If one frame could point to several frames, then we'd end up in [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), with a directed graph. What we would be looking for is a way to find a cycle (or potential cycle) in that graph. I'm unfortunately not an expert on that subject, but I would suggest either looking at this [blog post](http://neopythonic.blogspot.ca/2009/01/detecting-cycles-in-directed-graph.html) (since it was written by Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, I'm going to assume it's a good start), or bringing out the heavy guns and getting a full fledged [graph library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-graph/1.8.2).

Comment: Thanks, I see how that could apply to mine, it looks very complex though haha (to me, what I'm doing seems a bit like a reverse maze, where each node can pick its parent node). This is literally only for a single dropdown box in a user interface, so I can leave it for now and see if anyone else might be able to draft up something, but thanks for the links too. As it's in Maya, I'm unfortunately limited to the default libraries.

Comment: @Peter Good point, it's probably overkill. :-) I've added a simpler solution that gets the result you were looking for, with the example you gave. Hopefully, it's more inline with what you need.

Comment: Thanks so much, this appears to work perfectly :)    With the nature of what I'm doing and the fact both this and the other code takes around 0.000035 seconds, I don't think there's going to be a problem as to its speed haha.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answerer said, you're dealing with a directed acyclic graph. For each node, you want to find the set of all the parents of that node (all of the nodes from which that node is reachable), which is equivalent to finding the set of all of the children of that node (all of the nodes reachable from it) in the reversed graph (obtained by reversing the direction of each edge in your graph). I don't know how comfortable you are with graph theory, so it would be helpful if you would clarify that. (edit: I saw your comment, let me know if anything needs clarification)

Once you've obtained the reverse graph, you can find the set of children of a node in that graph in linear time here using depth-first search (DFS is O(|V|+|E|) where |V| is the number of nodes and |E| is the number of edges, but here we know that |E| <= |V|). So with only a basic implementation of DFS, you'll have to run it on each node in the graph and the entire thing will be O(|V|^2).

There may a more elegant way of finding the reverse graph, but what I have below gets the job done. This code requires using a slightly different representation of your frames, but I think this is easily obtainable from how you wrote it above.

```
from collections import defaultdict

frame_pointers = {5: set([6]),
              6: set([7]),
              7: set([8]),
              8: set(),
              9: set([10]),
              10: set(),
              11: set([9]),
              12: set([6])}

inverse_graph = defaultdict(list)
for x, adj in frame_pointers.items():
    for y in adj:
        inverse_graph[y].append(x)
inverse_graph = dict(inverse_graph)
for key in frame_pointers.keys():
    if inverse_graph.get(key) == None:
        inverse_graph[key] = set()
    else:
        inverse_graph[key] = set(inverse_graph[key])

def dfs(graph, start):
    visited, stack = set(), [start]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited
```

Given a starting node, DFS will return a list of all nodes reachable from that node.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I have to admit I was looking funnily at the output for a couple of seconds before I realised that was inverted too haha, but it's nice seeing two different ways after spending hours figuring it out, cheers :)